# Will LibreOffice advance ahead of Open Office eventually?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

Examining the differences between [LibreOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libreoffice) and [Open Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) and trying to understand what it's all about, would it be correct to assume that LibreOffice will eventually be overtaking Open Office in their advancement as both projects advance from the forking point as a result of simply the variety and number contributing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Libreoffice was founded, the majority of the full time staff working on OpenOffice moved to work on Libreoffice instead. That means the developers for Libreoffice are essential the same as those who worked on OpenOffice.org (plus a few new coders). Oracle recently announced that they were abandoning OpenOffice.org.

So really the answer to your question is that it already has and that users should switch to Libreoffice since they will not see significant additional support for OpenOffice.

Comment: Wow. So Open Office is pretty much dead.

Comment: Essentially! But LibreOffice is moving in leaps and bounds. And has freedom now from the commercial directives associated with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

so fat the only difference i saw between LO and OO is that libreoffice works much worse with equations and formulas from that are created in microsoft office
since i study math heavily, it's a  huge letdown for me.

to be specific libreoffice opens documents with a lot of equations 2-3 (sic!) times slower thatn openoffice and displays them even worse

also, libreoffice design (not interface, but apps icons, splash screen on start) are simply ugly. Which is shame because for everyday applications friendly design is just as important as functionality.

Comment: If you have to make a lot of math-related documents, I would *really, really* suggest you start using LaTeX. Hell, I would suggest using it for almost any document that's supposed to look good.

Answer (score 0):

Although LibreOffice Writer 3.5 saves documents in the Microsoft Office Word 2010 file format (.docx) and OpenOffice Writer 3.4 so far does not, the OO Writer is still the word processor closest to the standard word processors such as Microsoft Office Word. Both OO and LibreOffice resemble Word 2003 in many ways:

1. They save files in the Word 2003/95... format (.doc), which is still widely used today.
2. They read all Microsoft Office files.
3. They use the "ribbon-style" interface.

However, **OpenOffice has all of the standard Western fonts**, such as Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial, and more. LibreOffice's fonts are similar but NOT THE SAME and do not resemble the standard fonts on Microsoft Office. Believe me! I've tried it. The fonts look great on LibreOffice but not on Microsoft Office 2010.

Comment: Neither LibreOffice Writer nor OpenOffice.org Writer *default* to saving documents in any Microsoft Office format. They both default to saving documents in the OpenDocument format.

Comment: I'm not sure about OO, but I know LO does NOT have a ribbon-style interface.